# my avd in android studio never starts. Black screen

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I am using the latest version of android studio and every time I try to launch an emulator, it does not show the bootup logo or anything just a black screen. Does anyone know how to correct this?
[image: screenshot]
[image: error screenshot][image]

Comment: please paste your screenshot of screen and AVD Manager dialog

Comment: The avd dialog shows this _Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_27.avd/userdata.img_

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: this is a just a warning. delete this emulator and create a new one.

Comment: that does not work still. I have added a new screenshot error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem is using an emulator that uses little RAM. In my case is a Nexus. Previously I was trying to launch in a Pixel 2 XL. So, reducing the RAM used solved my case

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably you created your AVD with **x86** but your PC is **64-bit**.

Try to create an emulator with **x86_64** architecture. See below screenshot:

[image: 64-bit emulator]