# AVD is online, but doesn't show anything

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am developing an Android app in Android Studio. When I try to run it on an AVD, the AVD screen shows nothing.

The device frame is visible, but there is nothing inside it. The message "waiting for target device to come online" doesn't show up either.

Furthermore, I am unable to edit the graphics in the AVD settings. I have tried running the program both normally and from the AVD manager, but it doesn't work either way.

Other solutions which I have tried (and failed) are removing C:\Windows\System32\Wbem from the PATH environment variable, ending the ADB process in Task Manager, and wiping data from the AVD in AVD manager. Oh, and I even uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio but it still doesn't work, even for a basic Hello World program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR2LX.jpg

Comment: Try the option as I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280230/my-avd-in-android-studio-never-starts-black-screen/51354067#51354067

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem due to my ram several times and even after upgrading I had to make several changes. The best solution is to set up a new avd. use Nexus S, and a light image. Start with API 16 and when it works go ahead and create your desired AVD. Keep your eye on the pop up errors AVD shows like HAXM

Comment: Okay so I have tried it and it is now showing a black screen rather than just a frame, and gives an error installing APK.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem silly but have you checked if the emulator is not locked?
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have checked. Nothing has changed when I pressed the power button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when Emulator is not displaying anything and saying like, waiting for online, 
after click on power button then what you have to do is Go to,

**AVD Manager** then in **Actions** section click on **bottom triangle button** and click on **"Cold Boot Now"** to make working your Emulator.